# Set css style to an HTML textarea row

Tags: html, css

how can I set the style of a row in a textarea?
If I would like to have a bottom border to simulate a book?

Comment: Need more information or an example of what you're trying to achieve. You can't style an individual row inside a textarea - you can only style the text area as a whole ...

Comment: for short question there is a short answer:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_borders.asp

good luck

Answer (score -1):

Just set some proper css styles and a background-image for your textarea:

```
textarea {
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynxjD.png) repeat-y;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    font: normal 14px verdana;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    border: solid 1px #ddd;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/q3FhL/

Comment: This styles the entire textarea, not a row there, as asked.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Well let see how the OP react, but I don't think it's deserve a downvote though :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've already found this solution on the internet but this is not what I'm looking for. The output is good but I can't use a background image. :-(